# How to prevent event tracking data's instant update?

Tags: android, google-analytics, analytics

I have used google analytic for event tracker. I have set dispatch time as 24 hour. But my data is updating instantly . How can I prevent that??

Comment: Can you please show your code to help better assist you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GA event tracking data update instantly . To the top event and marge with other data after your provided time.